# Not found an file de MOIP on Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, credit-card

I just develop MOIP with ready-made components, but received the error after running.
Showed an error message:
"ld: file not found: /Users/teste/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Moip_Store-fakuiehavrpkaeggjvvtbovybkyh/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Moip Store.app/Moip Store
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

site: https://github.com/moip/ios-sdk-sample

Someone solve this problem?

how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Select your Project and choose your "Moip Store Test" - Target, go to "General" and set your Application as Host Application.